# Constant size priority queue - Insert first or delete first?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am using a `priority_queue` to store the K closest points found so far in a K-nearest-neighbor search. When I find a point closer than the point at the top of the queue, I want to pop the top element and push the new one.

```
if(point < pq.top()){
    pq.pop();
    pq.push(point);
}
```

Generally, is it more efficient to pop first and then insert, or is it more efficient to insert first and then pop?

Comment: What container class are you using to back the priority_queue?

Comment: @Null Set : Then isn't the answer self-evident? Knowing the behavior of `vector`, if you insert first and then pop, you have the *potential* to force the underlying `vector` to reallocate, whereas if you pop first and then insert, you don't. What are you asking about beyond that?

Comment: @ildjarn I'm assuming it is implemented as a heap. I was thinking about the number of swaps and compares it has to do to perform the underlying heap functions in those two cases.

Comment: Why use a priority queue if you are totally replacing the nearest point?  What is the priority based on? Why not just insert the point, then erase the furthest element (if you want to limit the size)?  Not sure what the goal of your use-case is.

Comment: @Will Priority is the distance of that point from the point I am searching for the nearest neighbors of. I'm erasing the furthest point.

Comment: @NullSet `std::priority_queue` is an adapter. The so called "heap" is actually a set of algorithms the library performs on top of your container of choice.

Comment: @NullSet that's not how a heap works. A heap only gives you the smallest, not the largest element. Or the other way around: it can give you the largest element, not the smallest.

Comment: @wilhelmtell I am not sure what you think I am trying to do, but I am well aware of that. The priority_queue/maxheap is holding the K closest points I have found, with the least close of these at the top of the queue. If I find a point closer than that least close of the closest K, I know it will be replacing that one in the queue, but not necessarily at the top.

Comment: If the performance is that big a concern, you would be better off starting from scratch. Then you can change the top element instead of popping it, and then do the trickle down operation as though you added a new element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `std::priority_queue` as your priority queue class, the standard container class `std::vector` is used for its underlying container class, by default.

Generally, it is less efficient to `push` first than `pop` first.

**Reason one**

Pushing an element in `priority_queue` will envoke `vector::push_back` which can potentially reallocate the underlying buffer if it exceeds it current capacity.

**Reason two**

> priority_queue::pop
>
> When you pop an element from
>   `priority_queue`, it calls the
>   `pop_heap` algorithm to keep the heap
>   property of priority_queues, and then
>   calls the member function `pop_back`
>   of the underlying container object to
>   remove the element.
>
> priority_queue::push
>
> When you push an element to
>   priority_queue, it calls the member
>   function `push_back` of the underlying
>   container object, and then calls the
>   `push_heap` algorithm to keep the heap
>   property of priority_queues.

Assume there are now **N** elements in priority queue.

If you `push` first, the algorithm `push_heap` is called two times, to adjust **N+1** and **N+1** elements, respectively.

If you `pop` first, the algorithm `push_heap` is called two times, to adjust **N** and **N** elements, respectively.

**Aside**

If you're implementing your own priority queue, this is probably a performance-saver. Since you already check the value with the top, I'm wondering if you can directly swap the element with the top without invoking the push/pop thus bypassing the heap adjusting algorithm. May not be practical though.

Comment: realloc+memcpy operations aren't going to be an issue with a FIXED SIZE queue.

Comment: @corlettk, Right. But practically when using with std::priority_queue, it's may not be fixed anyway.

Comment: Once the priority_queue gets up to size K it will oscillate between K and K+1, or K-1 and K depending on the order I choose. The realloc cost should only happen once.

Comment: @Null Set: If your program is single-threaded, your conclusion is true. Furthermore, I don't think reallocation overhead is a big deal by all means. As you're asking which one is "more" efficient instead of "how" efficient, I list it there. If your program isn't that time-critical, neither of them matters that much:)

Comment: For Golang heap, "directly swap the element with the top without invoking the push/pop" is doable.  According to https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#Fix, "Changing the value of the element at index i and then calling Fix is equivalent to, but less expensive than, calling Remove(h, i) followed by a Push of the new value."

Answer (score 1):

@NullSet,

You're implementing a K-nearest-neighbor-search, so I'm going to presume that **performance is a BIG concern**.

**If so**, Just one tip with using the standard-queue, see if you can back it with an array (I'm out of my own depth here)... I'm guessing this fixed-size, random-access construct will be a tad more efficient that vector.

Then, if your queue is STILL a proven performance bottleneck, I'd look at rolling-my-own implementation of the priority-queue interface based on a btree (or even an rbtree).

How far you go with this is REALLY dependant on your maximum *K*. If *K* is small enough the standard vector-backed priority queue will be darn-near-as-quick-as THE most efficient conceivable solution. The trick is to observe the ACTUAL performance of the running program, in order to identify those "opportunities for improvement" which are likely to yeild the best performance improvement for your efforts.

Yup, I'm an algorithm racing fan... does it show?

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: I may end up just implementing it myself. The operation I really want here is to replace the top of the heap with the new node and bubble down.